# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to+\infty}(x-1)e^{\pi/2+arctanx}-xe^{\pi}$

Tags: limits

I knew that
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}(x-1)e^{\pi/2+arctanx}-xe^{\pi}=\lim_{x\to+\infty}(x-1)e^{\pi}-xe^{\pi}=-e^{\pi}$$ is not correct.  But I have no idea how to do it correctly.

Comment: What are you allowed to use? Asymptotics? Hopital Rule? Just Algebra? :)

Comment: @H.R. Any method is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a step by step approach. I use the **summation and product theorem for limits** in conjunction with **L'Hopital's rule**.

$$\eqalign{
  & \,\,\,\,\,\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } (x\, - 1){e^{\pi /2 + arctanx}} - x{e^\pi }  \cr 
  &  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \left( {{e^{\pi /2 + arctanx}} - {e^\pi }} \right)x - {e^{\pi /2 + arctanx}}  \cr 
  &  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } {{\left( {{e^{\pi /2 + arctanx}} - {e^\pi }} \right)} \over {{1 \over x}}} - \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } {e^{\pi /2 + arctanx}}  \cr 
  &  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } {{{1 \over {1 + {x^2}}}{e^{\pi /2 + arctanx}}} \over { - {1 \over {{x^2}}}}} - \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } {e^{\pi /2 + arctanx}}  \cr 
  &  =  - \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } {{{x^2}} \over {1 + {x^2}}}{e^{\pi /2 + arctanx}} - \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } {e^{\pi /2 + arctanx}}  \cr 
  &  =  - \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } {{{x^2}} \over {1 + {x^2}}}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } {e^{\pi /2 + arctanx}} - \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } {e^{\pi /2 + arctanx}}  \cr 
  &  =  - (1)({e^\pi }) - ({e^\pi }) =  - 2{e^\pi } \cr} $$

Just to mention one more thing, always examine that in each step you are taking, what theorem or rule for limits you are using! The first step in your effort is **false**, i.e.

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } (x - 1){e^{\pi /2 + arctanx}} - x{e^\pi } \ne \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } (x - 1){e^\pi } - x{e^\pi }$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $\tan^{-1}x=\theta\implies x=\tan\theta$
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}(x-1)e^{\pi/2+\tan^{-1} x}-xe^{\pi}=\lim_{\theta \to \pi/2}(\tan\theta-1)e^{\pi/2+\theta}-e^{\pi}\tan\theta$$
$$=\lim_{\theta \to \pi/2}\tan\theta\left(e^{\pi/2+\theta}-e^{\pi}\right)-e^{\pi/2+\theta}$$
$$=\lim_{\theta \to \pi/2}\frac{e^{\pi/2+\theta}-e^{\pi}}{\cot \theta}-\lim_{\theta \to \pi/2}e^{\pi/2+\theta}$$

$$=\lim_{\theta \to \pi/2}\frac{\underbrace{e^{\pi/2+\theta}-e^{\pi}}_{\huge \to 0}}{\underbrace{\cot \theta}_{\huge \to 0}}-\lim_{\theta \to \pi/2}e^{\pi/2+\theta}$$

Applying L'Hospital's rule for $\frac{0}{0}$ form 
$$=\lim_{\theta \to \pi/2}\frac{\frac{d}{d\theta}(e^{\pi/2+\theta}-e^{\pi})}{\frac{d}{d\theta}(\cot \theta)}-e^{\pi/2+\pi/2}$$
$$=\lim_{\theta \to \pi/2}\frac{e^{\pi/2+\theta}}{(-\csc^2 \theta)}-e^{\pi}$$
$$=-\frac{e^{\pi/2+\pi/2}}{\csc^2 \frac{\pi}{2}}-e^{\pi}$$
$$=-\frac{e^{\pi}}{1}-e^{\pi}=\color{red}{-2e^{\pi}}$$

Comment: yes, you are right, but observe $\lim_{\theta\to \pi/2}\cot\theta=0 $So apply L'Hospital's rule for $\frac{0}{0}$ form for the following $$\lim_{\theta\to \pi/2}\frac{e^{\pi/2+\theta}-e^{\pi}}{\cot \theta}$$